# Show the Phone options screen from my Application

Tags: android

Is it possible to show/pop-up the phone options screen? Its the screen that pops up when a user long presses the power button. On my Samsung Galaxy S3, it has the following options:
1. Power Off
2. Data Network mode
3. Restart
4. Mute/Vibrate/Sound

Basically, I want to show this screen when a user clicks on a button in my App. Any ideas??

Thanks
Ameya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code, you'll see it's handled internally (PhoneWindowManager.java and GlobalActions.java). There is no interface whatsoever through the API.

In short: Can't be done.

Comment: Thanks Dalmas, was just trying to make it easy for the Users :)